# In python by what logic we can add "for" loop with another statement as it is done in the mentioned example?

Tags: python, for-loop

In the below function, while loop condition has 2 statements/expressions "x in my_string" and "for x in brackets", by what logic both can be mentioned together?

```
def check(my_string): 
    brackets = ['()', '{}', '[]'] 
    while any(x in my_string for x in brackets):# How can 2 statements be mentioned
        for br in brackets: 
            my_string = my_string.replace(br, '') 
    return not my_string
```

Comment: Exactly what do you want to do here, strip all the `()`, `{}` and `[]`s?

Comment: simple thing overcomplicated

Comment: What do you want to achieve here? Please provide example inputs and outputs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a language construct known as a *generator expression*.  Read more here: https://djangostars.com/blog/list-comprehensions-and-generator-expressions/

Answer (score 1):

the `for x in brackets` parts is indeed a comprehension,

but the `x in my_string` part is just the `in` operator. like `'bcd' in 'abcdefg'` or `2 in [1,2,3]`, the result of which is Boolean.

`any` is then used to check if at least one of those Booleans is True.